# Modify Java object field from JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

i want to declare an int a = 5  in java (android) and modify it using ndk  with c/c++ , and change the value of int a in jni , basically its accessing that segment of ram which variable is declared , but i dont know how to do that ?

```
public class dataclass {                                                                
int a = 5;                                                                          
int b = 5;                                                                          
                                                                                    
static {                                                                            
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");                                               
}                                                                                   
public native void changeValue(dataclass mclass);
```

}

Comment: You need to use the appropriate JNI functions (e.g. `GetFieldID`, `SetIntField`). Consult [the JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you declared your `changeValue` as a `static` function in Java, your native code will receive three parameters: a `JNIEnv * env`, a `jclass cls`, and `jobject obj`. The latter is the instance of `dataclass` you want to manipulate.

The approach is then standard:

1. Get a reference to the `dataclass` class using `env->FindClass("dataclass")` or `env->GetObjectClass(obj)`
2. Use that reference to get a handle to the field you want to modify using `env->GetFieldID(dataClass, "a", "I")`. The `I` here is the primitive type associated with `int`.
3. Finally, make the change by calling `env->SetIntField(obj, fieldId, new_value)`